# Node.js fs get icon of files in directory

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file-io, node-webkit

I want to build a file system explorer app, and I want to list files with icons. I use node-webkit.
And files can be executables, directories and normally files. In file list I want to diplay files icon and name.

Can I use node.js fs module for getting icons? Or there a module for reading icons?

How can I get icon of file?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean when said about icon. If it's the icon as the icon which display in windows/mac 's folder, I think you cannot do it. But you could do it by mapping icon. example, `var prefix = file.name.match(/[^\.][\w\d]*$/); file.icon = iconList[prefix]`, build an array with `iconList = [ { 'exe' : 'exe.png'} , 'pdf' : 'pdf.png'} ]`

Answer (score 2):

Icons are dependent on the operating system / browser application and aren't a generic interface provided by node.js - you instead need to first resolve the type of file, then pick and show the icon for that type of file.

You can use the `fs` module for resolving the type - especially [stats](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats).

The type of icon to show is up to you - some operating systems may provide these for you, but it is up to you to find their location.