# How to get the default icon for a file in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, icons

I am creating a file explorer in NodeJS.

My question is, how do I find or get the icon for a file, like they do in Windows File Explorer.

I understand that this may be different for each OS, so a separate answer for each OS would be ideal (or just Windows would also be fine for now).

I'm sure it's possible from this: [How to get the default system icon for a drive, a device or a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805944/how-to-get-the-default-system-icon-for-a-drive-a-device-or-a-file)

However, that uses delphi and I am finding very confusing to understand their code.

Comment: Related question: [Node.js fs get icon of files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317050/node-js-fs-get-icon-of-files-in-directory)

Comment: @jfriend00 Looked at that, but there's not really an answer. It just says it's different for different OS. It dosen't help me find it. Also the above link in my question suggest there is a solution!

Comment: Also: [Extracting Windows Icons with Node.js](http://sciencevikinglabs.com/icon-extractor/)

Comment: That has a 404 error lol (and I have tried to look at that before).

Comment: No 404 for me at http://sciencevikinglabs.com/icon-extractor/.  It uses a native program for getting access to the windows-specific info.  That's what you're going to have to do.

Comment: That's wired. Maybe you have a cached version or only works in a different country, but it's 404 for me. But anyway I would like a proper solution with code if possible.

Comment: Can you go here: http://sciencevikinglabs.com/ and then find the right article in the list?  It comes with code.

Comment: Actually that site woks on my mobile for some reason. Looks good. Will check it out